# How to update Data Extention row without creating a new record

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

i am very new for marketing cloud and I am having this problem.I have a Data Extention containig a list of Subscribers with their email and subscriber key.I build a form working well, which can post entery in to DE but i want to stop users to send this form more then once. IF the user alredy in DE must redirect to other page name : you already signed in.
i have the following code but somehow create always new record insted of updating the existing record. Thanks alot for your help.

```
var idRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('IDE_Form_Data','IDE_Form_Data_Key',IDE_Form_Data_Key);
            if(idRows>0) {
              Platform.Function.UpdateData("IDE_Form_Data",["IDE_Form_Data_Key"],[IDE_Form_Data_Key],["Fieldvalue_txt_1", "Form_Phone_Num", "Subscriber_Key", "Form_Id", "Form_Name", "Form_Type", "Fieldname_txt_1", "Journey_Desc", "Form_Insert_Date"],[Fieldvalue_txt_1,Form_Phone_Num,Subscriber_Key,Form_Id,Form_Name,Form_Type,Fieldname_txt_1,Journey_Desc,DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())]);
              Platform.Response.Redirect("https://youalreadysignedinpage", false);
            } else {
              Platform.Function.InsertDE("IDE_Form_Data",["IDE_Form_Data_Key", "Fieldvalue_txt_1", "Form_Phone_Num", "Subscriber_Key", "Form_Id", "Form_Name", "Form_Type", "Fieldname_txt_1", "Journey_Desc", "Form_Insert_Date"],[IDE_Form_Data_Key,Fieldvalue_txt_1,Form_Phone_Num,Subscriber_Key,Form_Id,Form_Name,Form_Type,Fieldname_txt_1,Journey_Desc,DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())]);
            }
            Platform.Response.Redirect("https://thankyoupage", false);
```

Comment: Do you try to set a fixed existing record to test yet?

Comment: yes i do have existing record to test

Comment: and everytime create a new Record in Data Extention when i send the Form :(

Answer (score 1):

The `LookupRows` function will return an array if a rowset is found. So your check condition was wrong. You can read the [examples of the function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookupRows.html) to understand.

Try this:

```
var idRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('IDE_Form_Data','IDE_Form_Data_Key',IDE_Form_Data_Key);
            if(idRows && idRows.length > 0) {
              Platform.Function.UpdateData("IDE_Form_Data",["IDE_Form_Data_Key"],[IDE_Form_Data_Key],["Fieldvalue_txt_1", "Form_Phone_Num", "Subscriber_Key", "Form_Id", "Form_Name", "Form_Type", "Fieldname_txt_1", "Journey_Desc", "Form_Insert_Date"],[Fieldvalue_txt_1,Form_Phone_Num,Subscriber_Key,Form_Id,Form_Name,Form_Type,Fieldname_txt_1,Journey_Desc,DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())]);
              Platform.Response.Redirect("https://youalreadysignedinpage", false);
            } else {
              Platform.Function.InsertDE("IDE_Form_Data",["IDE_Form_Data_Key", "Fieldvalue_txt_1", "Form_Phone_Num", "Subscriber_Key", "Form_Id", "Form_Name", "Form_Type", "Fieldname_txt_1", "Journey_Desc", "Form_Insert_Date"],[IDE_Form_Data_Key,Fieldvalue_txt_1,Form_Phone_Num,Subscriber_Key,Form_Id,Form_Name,Form_Type,Fieldname_txt_1,Journey_Desc,DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())]);
            }
            Platform.Response.Redirect("https://thankyoupage", false);
```

Comment: Hi i rebuild my if condition but still i have the same problem :(

Comment: @hilmi If you set a fixed value in `IDE_Form_Data_Key` variable which you already know is from an existing record. What is the page it would redirect to? Does it create a new record in the DE?

Comment: If the form is in a Cloudpage, you need to save and republish it as well

Comment: i figured out and i dont have a fixed record for IDE_Form_Data_Key (its change always)but i do have a fixed record for Subscriber_Key. So i need to use Subscriber_Key insted of Ide_Form_Data_Key.the Form is in CLoudpage like you said but somehow i think i need a for loop right ? but how can i ask to marketing cloud ?if user already  exist with same SUbscriber_Key then dont write in DE but redirect to other page

Comment: and one more quation what exacly do this line of code ? i Mean sure its lookupRows func bring me  where i want to select but what is the perpuse of  this -- if (idRows && idRows.lengt >0)

Comment: @hilmi I don't know the whole context, so depends on the case you are working for, you may need additional steps to make the variable IDE_Form_Data_Key has a fixed value for testing. The line `if(idRows && idRows.length > 0)` is for checking if the user is already in the "IDE_Form_Data" DE or not, if yes then it will update data, else it will insert a new record